# How to add a line of text to a text file being read in, C#

Tags: c#, append

I am reading in a file that contains the contents for movies such as the ID, movie title, genre, release year, and if the movie is available or not.

Example:

> 01#Inside Out#Comedy#2015#True
>
> 02#Inside Out#Comedy#2015#True
>
> 03#Toy Story 4#Family#2019#True
>
> 04#Toy Story 4#Family#2019#True

What I would like to do is add another movie to the .txt file, directly beneath all the other movies. How could I prompt the user to enter each value for the movie, and have it saved in the same file as the rest of the movies?

Comment: `File.AppendAllText()` Next question?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to write the line is something like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:\\some\\path\\movies.txt")) 
{
    sw.WriteLine("New line");            
}
```

How you choose to provide the actual data that goes into that file is up to you. That depends on what type of application you have, i.e. whether it is a GUI- or a console application.

In either case, code similar to the above will append text (in this case `New line`) to the end of the specified file.

If you want to add those specific values using variables, you might replace the line that writes content with:

```
sw.WriteLine($"{id}#{title} #{genre}#{year}#{available}");
```

...and then provide values for each of the variables. In essence, do the following for each movie (note - I'm just guessing the meaning of the last value; the boolean true/false):

```
var id= "123";
var title = "Great misadventures in code";
var genre = "SciFi/Horror";
var year = "2021";
var available = "No";
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `File.AppendAllText` is the method to use, but note that it does not inserts newline, so you have to include it in appneded text, like:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"path to file", $"\n{Id}#{Title}#{Genre}#{ReleaseYear}#{Available}");
```

where variables in {} hold appropriate values inputted by user.